# How to configure hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces properly

Tags: hibernate, connection, c3p0

Searched almost everywhere for the solution but did not find any direction. I want debug logs printed for unreturned connection stacktrace for c3p0 connection pooling. I have following properties set in configuration for hibernate apart from other properties of c3p0.

i.e.

```
          <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">30</beans:prop>
          <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</beans:prop>
```

other properties are

```
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</beans:prop>
```

Other properties are getting printed in logs at the time of spring container initialization as

```
             com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource - Initializing c3p0 pool... 
             com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@22c564ca [ connectionPoolDataSource -> 
             com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@2e5953fe [ acqui...
```

But for all unreturned connections i am unable to see any logs related.

Here are my other configurations in log4j.xml

```
            <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
                      <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
                      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
                      </layout>
             </appender>
             <logger name="com.mchange.v2.c3p0">
                 <level value="info"/>
             </logger>
```

Is there anything i am missing to configure. Please help.

Comment: You should be able to verify the settings are as you intend in the mapping printed on initialization after `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@2e5953fe [`

Comment: The debug stack traces will be printed lazily, as unreturned Connections time out. Look for `Exception` stack traces with the message `DEBUG STACK TRACE: Overdue resource check-out stack trace.`